# Android Studio and SDK 25.1.1 emulator images issue

Tags: android-studio, android-sdk-tools

Donwloading recent Android SDK to my 4.2.0-23-generic #28~14.04.1-Ubuntu x86_64 linux box and i can't setup the basic development environment.

During the Studio configuration it fails to setup Virtual Device images with an error message:

```
Ignoring unknown package filter 'sys-img-x86-addon-google_apis-google-23'
```

If i'll try to use command line to install emulator images i faced with an issue that there is no images at all!

```
$ ./android  --verbose --clear-cache list sdk -a
SDK Manager repository: manifest cache cleared.
Refresh Sources:
  Fetching https://dl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list-2.xml
  Validate XML
  Parse XML
  Fetched Add-ons List successfully
  Refresh Sources
  Fetching URL: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/repository-11.xml
  Validate XML: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/repository-11.xml
  Parse XML:    https://dl.google.com/android/repository/repository-11.xml
  Fetching URL: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/addon.xml
  Validate XML: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/addon.xml
  Parse XML:    https://dl.google.com/android/repository/addon.xml
  Fetching URL: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/addon-6.xml
  Validate XML: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/addon-6.xml
  Parse XML:    https://dl.google.com/android/repository/addon-6.xml
  Fetching URL: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/glass/addon.xml
  Validate XML: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/glass/addon.xml
  Parse XML:    https://dl.google.com/android/repository/glass/addon.xml
  Fetching URL: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/extras/intel/addon.xml
  Validate XML: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/extras/intel/addon.xml
  Parse XML:    https://dl.google.com/android/repository/extras/intel/addon.xml
  Fetching URL: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/android/sys-img.xml
  Fetching URL: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/android-wear/sys-img.xml
  Fetching URL: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/android-tv/sys-img.xml
  Fetching URL: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/google_apis/sys-img.xml
  Fetching URL: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/x86/addon.xml
Refresh Sources:
  Fetching URL: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/android/sys-img.xml
  Fetching URL: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/android-wear/sys-img.xml
  Fetching URL: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/android-tv/sys-img.xml
  Fetching URL: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/google_apis/sys-img.xml
  Fetching URL: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/x86/addon.xml
Packages available for installation or update: 98
   1- Android SDK Tools, revision 25.1.1
   2- Android SDK Platform-tools, revision 23.1
   3- Android SDK Platform-tools, revision 24 rc1
   4- Android SDK Build-tools, revision 24 rc2
   5- Android SDK Build-tools, revision 23.0.3
   6- Android SDK Build-tools, revision 23.0.2
   7- Android SDK Build-tools, revision 23.0.1
   8- Android SDK Build-tools, revision 23 (Obsolete)
   9- Android SDK Build-tools, revision 22.0.1
  10- Android SDK Build-tools, revision 22 (Obsolete)
  11- Android SDK Build-tools, revision 21.1.2
  12- Android SDK Build-tools, revision 21.1.1 (Obsolete)
  13- Android SDK Build-tools, revision 21.1 (Obsolete)
  14- Android SDK Build-tools, revision 21.0.2 (Obsolete)
  15- Android SDK Build-tools, revision 21.0.1 (Obsolete)
  16- Android SDK Build-tools, revision 21 (Obsolete)
  17- Android SDK Build-tools, revision 20
  18- Android SDK Build-tools, revision 19.1
  19- Android SDK Build-tools, revision 19.0.3 (Obsolete)
  20- Android SDK Build-tools, revision 19.0.2 (Obsolete)
  21- Android SDK Build-tools, revision 19.0.1 (Obsolete)
  22- Android SDK Build-tools, revision 19 (Obsolete)
  23- Android SDK Build-tools, revision 18.1.1 (Obsolete)
  24- Android SDK Build-tools, revision 18.1 (Obsolete)
  25- Android SDK Build-tools, revision 18.0.1 (Obsolete)
  26- Android SDK Build-tools, revision 17 (Obsolete)
  27- Documentation for Android SDK, API 23, revision 1
  28- SDK Platform Android 6.0, API 23, revision 3
  29- SDK Platform Android N Preview, revision 1
  30- SDK Platform Android 5.1.1, API 22, revision 2
  31- SDK Platform Android 5.0.1, API 21, revision 2
  32- SDK Platform Android 4.4W.2, API 20, revision 2
  33- SDK Platform Android 4.4.2, API 19, revision 4
  34- SDK Platform Android 4.3.1, API 18, revision 3
  35- SDK Platform Android 4.2.2, API 17, revision 3
  36- SDK Platform Android 4.1.2, API 16, revision 5
  37- SDK Platform Android 4.0.3, API 15, revision 5
  38- SDK Platform Android 4.0, API 14, revision 4
  39- SDK Platform Android 3.2, API 13, revision 1
  40- SDK Platform Android 3.1, API 12, revision 3
  41- SDK Platform Android 3.0, API 11, revision 2
  42- SDK Platform Android 2.3.3, API 10, revision 2
  43- SDK Platform Android 2.3.1, API 9, revision 2
  44- SDK Platform Android 2.2, API 8, revision 3
  45- SDK Platform Android 2.1, API 7, revision 3
  46- SDK Platform Android 2.0.1, API 6, revision 1 (Obsolete)
  47- SDK Platform Android 2.0, API 5, revision 1 (Obsolete)
  48- SDK Platform Android 1.6, API 4, revision 3 (Obsolete)
  49- SDK Platform Android 1.5, API 3, revision 4 (Obsolete)
  50- SDK Platform Android 1.1, API 2, revision 1 (Obsolete)
  51- Google APIs, Android API 23, revision 1
  52- Google APIs, Android API 22, revision 1
  53- Google APIs, Android API 21, revision 1
  54- Google APIs, Android API 19, revision 18
  55- Glass Development Kit Preview, Android API 19, revision 11
  56- Google APIs, Android API 18, revision 4
  57- Google APIs, Android API 17, revision 4
  58- Google APIs, Android API 16, revision 4
  59- Google APIs, Android API 15, revision 3
  60- Google APIs, Android API 14, revision 2 (Obsolete)
  61- Google APIs, Android API 13, revision 1 (Obsolete)
  62- Google TV Addon, Android API 13, revision 1 (Obsolete)
  63- Google APIs, Android API 12, revision 1 (Obsolete)
  64- Google TV Addon, Android API 12, revision 2 (Obsolete)
  65- Google APIs, Android API 11, revision 1 (Obsolete)
  66- Google APIs, Android API 10, revision 2 (Obsolete)
  67- Google APIs, Android API 9, revision 2 (Obsolete)
  68- Google APIs, Android API 8, revision 2 (Obsolete)
  69- Google APIs, Android API 7, revision 1 (Obsolete)
  70- Google APIs, Android API 6, revision 1 (Obsolete)
  71- Google APIs, Android API 5, revision 1 (Obsolete)
  72- Google APIs, Android API 4, revision 2 (Obsolete)
  73- Google APIs, Android API 3, revision 3 (Obsolete)
  74- Sources for Android SDK, API 23, revision 1
  75- Sources for Android SDK, API 22, revision 1
  76- Sources for Android SDK, API 21, revision 1
  77- Sources for Android SDK, API 20, revision 1
  78- Sources for Android SDK, API 19, revision 2
  79- Sources for Android SDK, API 18, revision 1
  80- Sources for Android SDK, API 17, revision 1
  81- Sources for Android SDK, API 16, revision 2
  82- Sources for Android SDK, API 15, revision 2
  83- Sources for Android SDK, API 14, revision 1 (Obsolete)
  84- GPU Debugging tools, revision 1.0.3
  85- Android Support Repository, revision 28
  86- Android Support Library, revision 23.2.1
  87- Google AdMob Ads SDK, revision 11 (Obsolete)
  88- Google Analytics App Tracking SDK, revision 3 (Obsolete)
  89- Android Auto Desktop Head Unit emulator, revision 1.1
  90- Google Cloud Messaging for Android Library, revision 3 (Obsolete)
  91- Google Play services for Froyo, revision 12 (Obsolete)
  92- Google Play services, revision 29
  93- Google Repository, revision 25
  94- Google Play APK Expansion library, revision 1
  95- Google Play Licensing Library, revision 1
  96- Google Play Billing Library, revision 5
  97- Android Auto API Simulators, revision 1
  98- Google Web Driver, revision 2
```

What's wrong and how to setup development tools on fresh linux box?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you get only `Fetching URL` for sys-img xml files. There should also have `Parse XML` and `Validate XML` lines.

Not really your issue, but I came here because I failed to install `sys-img-x86_64-addon-google_apis-google-23` as it was declared since months in our scripts.

`Error: Ignoring unknown package filter 'sys-img-x86_64-addon-google_apis-google-23'`

```
Refresh Sources:
  Fetching https://dl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list-2.xml
  Validate XML
  Parse XML
  Fetched Add-ons List successfully
  Refresh Sources
  Fetching URL: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/repository-11.xml
  Validate XML: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/repository-11.xml
  Parse XML:    https://dl.google.com/android/repository/repository-11.xml
  Fetching URL: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/addon.xml
  Validate XML: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/addon.xml
  Parse XML:    https://dl.google.com/android/repository/addon.xml
  Fetching URL: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/glass/addon.xml
  Validate XML: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/glass/addon.xml
  Parse XML:    https://dl.google.com/android/repository/glass/addon.xml
  Fetching URL: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/extras/intel/addon.xml
  Validate XML: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/extras/intel/addon.xml
  Parse XML:    https://dl.google.com/android/repository/extras/intel/addon.xml
  Fetching URL: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/android/sys-img.xml
  Validate XML: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/android/sys-img.xml
  Parse XML:    https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/android/sys-img.xml
  Fetching URL: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/android-wear/sys-img.xml
  Validate XML: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/android-wear/sys-img.xml
  Parse XML:    https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/android-wear/sys-img.xml
  Fetching URL: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/android-tv/sys-img.xml
  Validate XML: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/android-tv/sys-img.xml
  Parse XML:    https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/android-tv/sys-img.xml
  Fetching URL: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/google_apis/sys-img.xml
  Validate XML: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/google_apis/sys-img.xml
  Parse XML:    https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/google_apis/sys-img.xml
  Fetching URL: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/x86/addon-x86.xml
  Validate XML: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/x86/addon-x86.xml
  Parse XML:    https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/x86/addon-x86.xml
Error: Ignoring unknown package filter 'sys-img-x86_64-addon-google_apis-google-23'
```

Using `android  --verbose --clear-cache list sdk -a -e` (`-e`) I've finally found that `sys-img-x86_64-addon-google_apis-google-23` was renamed to `sys-img-x86_64-google_apis-23`

```
----------
id: 60 or "sys-img-x86_64-google_apis-23"
     Type: SystemImage
     Desc: Google APIs Intel x86 Atom_64 System Image
           Revision 12
           Requires SDK Platform Android API 23
----------
```